# Ubuntu Crashes after Screenshot

Tags: 16.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

My Ubuntu 16.04 has been hanging regularly after taking screenshots using the native screenshot app. The following scenarios have been observed:-
a) The screen freezes with a black rectangle over the area where I have taken the screenshot and screenshot application closes. On repeatedly opening the screenshot application, I get the prompt to save after 10-11 tries. 
b) The system just freezes and nothing works ==> I have to do a hard restart with the power button. 
Please help.

Comment: How are you "opening the screenshot application"? I've never opened anything just pressed "Print Screen" key or "Alt"+"Print Screen"...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I open by typing Screenshot in the Dash

Comment: Does it lock up when press the Print Screen key?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No it's working fine with Print-screen. It's only when I select small rectangular areas using the Select Area to Grab option that it freezes.

Comment: After you use print screen you open launcher and right click on camera icon and pick option "select area of screen'?

Comment: No. [Case 1]: I use printscreen, it works. No issues here except I get my whole screen which I don't want. [Case 2]: When I use the screenshot app, I select the option 'Select area of screen', which is functionally different from printscreen. In this case it crashes.

Comment: Don't press Print Screen and then ENTER to capture whole screen Try what I wrote in my last comment which works for me to get selected area.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I press `Print Screen` it works, however it crashes (I get a crash report) when I press `Alt + Print Screen` to screenshot the current window...